# Is it faster to aggregate or aggregate and merge with one-to-many vars with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` like the following:

```
dt <- data.table(data.frame(
  id = rep(1:3, each=5),
  age = rep(10*(2:4), each=5),
  var = rnorm(15)
))
```

I want to aggregate over `var` using, say, a sum, but I must keep "age" a one-to-many variable, in the output.

One way to do this is:

```
dt <- merge(dt[, .(vsum=sum(var)), by=id], unique(dt[, c('id', 'age']), by='id')
```

Another way is

```
dt <- dt[, .(vsum=sum(var)), by=c('id', 'age')]
```

My gut says the second case loses time because `by=` looks for differing values of `age` within `ids`, which may be problematic if `age` is 20 or more variables. My gut says `merge` is problematic because the overall larger number of operations, and only a subset of those is `by=` within a `[.data.table` instance.

I can explore stupid cases like this, but don't have a sense of the general operating characteristics in terms of 1. When there are many many-to-one variables (like age), and if there data are dense with observations (many rows and few IDs) or dense with individuals (same N of rows but many IDs)

Is there any general, efficient approach to doing summary datasets such as this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the implementation.  However, why not do this?

```
dt[, .(vsum=sum(var), age=age[1]), by="id"]
```

Edit: Benchmarking below.

```
dt <- data.table(data.frame(
  id = rep(1:10000, each=5),
  age = rep(10*(1:10000), each=5),
  var = rnorm(150000)
))

res1 <- function() {merge(dt[, .(vsum=sum(var)), by="id"], unique(dt[, c('id', 'age')]), by='id')}
res2 <- function() {dt[, .(vsum=sum(var)), by=c('id', 'age')]}
res3 <- function() {dt[, .(vsum=sum(var), age=unique(age)), by="id"]}
res4 <- function() {dt[, .(vsum=sum(var), age=age[1]), by="id"]}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(res1(),res2(), res3(), res4(), times=10)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 res1()  6.940417  7.949203  9.250408  8.791923  9.695110 13.448288    10  b 
 res2()  3.796992  3.898165  4.889812  4.507141  4.790384  9.477044    10 a  
 res3() 48.259783 52.026664 55.401017 54.986112 59.375380 60.804102    10   c
 res4()  2.646796  2.853593  3.709116  3.252362  3.391909  6.321708    10 a
```

So it turns out, contrary to intuition, the 2nd approach is quite fast, with the fastest being the 4th approach.

Comment: Sorry, it is a "larger" version of the data, see the edit.

Comment: There's a reason the second/fourth approach wins -- run with `verbose = TRUE`, see `?GForce` and update your intuition :)